# True or False? Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

If the function $f+g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then the functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are also continuous.

False;

Let $f(x)=\begin{cases} -1 \text{ if } x<0 \\ 1 \text{ if } x\ge 0 \end{cases}$ $\hspace{10pt}$ and $\hspace{10pt}$ $g(x)=\begin{cases} 1 \text{ if } x<0 \\ -1 \text{ if } x\ge 0 \end{cases}$

Then $(f+g)(x)=0 \hspace{10pt}\forall x$.

Here, $f+g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, but the functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are not continuous.

Is this a good example?

Comment: Looks good. ${}{}{}$

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to know if this example would work.

Comment: You are correct.  Full marks!

Comment: Perhaps you might wish to elaborate your answer into a more general answer? Suppose $f$ is *any* discontinuous function and $h$ is *any* continuous function, can you find $g$ such that $$f(x)+g(x)=h(x)?$$

Comment: Here is an analogy to this result. The sum of two rational numbers is always rational (_cf._ the sum of two continuous real-valued functions is always continuous) but the sum of two irrational numbers _may be_ rational (example: $\sqrt{2}+(2-\sqrt{2})=2$; _cf_. the sum of two discontinuous functions may be continuous).

Comment: @AD. This is actually similar to my next question: If $g(x)$ is continuous and $(f+g)(x)$ is also continuous, is $f(x)$ continuous? I feel like it must be but I'm not quite sure. In your case, I feel like there would be no $g(x)$ to make the statement true.

Comment: $f(x) = (f+g)(x) - g(x)$. Not only the sum, also the difference of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: @TheMobiusLoops Here are two hints: First prove that there is at most one such $g$. Secondly, consider a point $a$ where $f$ is discontinuous - what does the definition of continuity say about $f$, $h,$ and $g$ at $a$?

Comment: If you put down the answer, I am sure you will get cred and can close the issue of this post.

Comment: If $f$ and $h$ are continuous at $a$ then $g$ must be continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(CW response so this doesn't appear as unanswered.)

The example is correct, but (depending on the class) you may wish to provide a proof that $f$ and $g$ are not continuous. In particular, you could prove that $f$ is not continuous at $0$, and then observe $g$ is not continuous either, since $g = -f$.

Proving the $0$ function is continuous shouldn't be too much trouble.